# M-theory compactified on $S^4$

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification

I am trying to understand what happens to the 32 supersymmetries of M-theory when it is compactified on $S^4$, with the other seven dimensions being flat, e.g., $\mathbb{R^7}$, $\mathbb{R^6} \times S^1$, or $\mathbb{R^5} \times S^1 \times S^1$. From what I have read, $S^4$ admits Killing spinors, so I believe some number of supersymmetries should be preserved in the 11-dimensional spacetime of M-theory. My question is, how many supersymmetries are actually preserved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in section 8.3 of:

Paul de Medeiros, José Figueroa-O'Farrill, "Half-BPS M2-brane orbifolds", Adv. Theor. Math. Phys. Volume 16, Number 5 (2012), 1349-1408 ([arXiv:1007.4761](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4761))

> In this case, we are interested in supersymmetric backgrounds
>   $\mathrm{AdS}_7 \times X^4$, with $X$ possibly an orbifold. Bär's
>   construction, together with the non-existence of irreducible
>   five-dimensional holonomy representations, imply that the only
>   (complete) four-dimensional manifold admitting real Killing spinors is
>   the round sphere $S^4$, hence any other supersymmetric background must
>   be an orbifold of $S^4$ by a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(5)$,
>   lifting isometrically to a subgroup $\Gamma < \mathrm{Sp}(2)$.  The
>   space of Killing spinors is again identified with the
>   $\Gamma$-invariant parallel spinors on $\mathrm{R}^5$ which is the
>   irreducible spinor representation $\Delta$ of $\mathrm{Sp}(2)$.  This
>   representation is quaternionic, whence the space of $\Gamma$-invariant
>   spinors is a quaternionic subspace: if a spinor is invariant, so is
>   its quaternion line, by the quaternion-linearity of the action of
>   $\mathrm{Sp}(2)$.  Since $\dim_\mathbb{H}\Delta =2$, necessarily
>   $0\leq \dim_\mathbb{H}\Delta^\Gamma \leq 2$.  Hence if we demand some
>   supersymmetry, either $\Gamma = \{1\}$ and we have $X = S^4$, or else
>   the orbifold is half-BPS.  In this case $\Gamma$ is contained in an
>   $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ subgroup of $\mathrm{Sp}(2)$, leaving a nonzero
>   vector invariant in the fundamental representation of
>   $\mathrm{Sp}(2)$.  Up to automorphisms, we see that $\Gamma$ is one of
>   the ADE subgroups in Table 1, but this time embedded in
>   $\mathrm{Sp}(2)$ in such a way that if $u \in \Gamma < \mathrm{Sp}(1)$
>   and $(x,y)\in\mathbb{H}^2$, then $u \cdot (x,y) = (ux,y)$.
>
> The action of that $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(5)$ on
>   $S^4$ is given by restricting the action on $\mathrm{RR}^5$.  This is
>   given as follows.  First of all, there is a vector which is fixed,
>   call it $\nu$.  If we identify the four-dimensional subspace
>   perpendicular to $\nu$ with $\mathbb{H}$, then the action of
>   $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ is by left quaternion multiplication.  Finally, using
>   the arguments described in Section 7.1 and in particular Table 11, it
>   is a simple exercise to decompose such orbifolds $S^4/\Gamma$, except
>   for $\Gamma = \mathbb{E}_8$, into a sequence of cyclic quotients. This
>   should become useful if and when we understand the six-dimensional
>   superconformal field theory dual to $\mathrm{AdS}_7 \times S^4$.

Comment: I copied the 8.3 here, but I am not sure it is correct. Could you please delete the not important parts?

Comment: I think it should be added that $S^4$ admits four Killing (Dirac) spinors.